# Change PHP configuration on Hetzner server

Tags: php

I need to change max_input_vars conf in php.
I changed php.ini and restart nginx. but it didn't help
[image]

I changed php.ini in /etc/php/7.3/fpm/

Comment: You will probably need to restart php-fpm, something like `sudo systemctl restart php7.3-fpm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changes do you execute `systemctl reload php7.3-fpm.service`?